# System.FormatException on TimeSpan.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, timespan

I have a float that represent a quantity of seconds and I need to format it to match this:

I need to format an elapsed time (in seconds) like this:

```
HH:mm:ss.fff // Like 01:15:22.150
```

Here is my code:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, h, m, s, ms);
string time = timeSpan.ToString(@"HH\:mm\:ss.fff"); // Throw a System.FormatException
```

It don't throw exception if I use ´@"hh:mm:ss"´ but I need the milliseconds...

What is the right string format?

I use this [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c7z43tw(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's 2 problems:

1. There is no `HH` format specifier for `TimeSpan`, use lower case version `hh` ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings))
2. You need to escape the `.` literal

Which makes the correct version:

```
string time = timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
```

You can also specify literal strings by surrounding them with `'`. For example:

```
string time = timeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'fff");
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: spaces must also be treated accordingly (meaning: must be escaped).